# What does -o mean when running spider crawl?

Tags: python, scrapy, command-line-interface

When using:

```
scrapy crawl nameOfSpider -o nameOfDataFile.csv -t csv
```

What do -o and -t do?

I'm using:

```
scrapy crawl redditSearch -o reddit.csv -t csv
```

I'm just curious.

Comment: name of output file ?

Comment: o for output file name and t for type of the file

Answer (score 1):

Many command line tools provide their own usage guide.

Run `scrapy crawl` with no arguments or pass in the conventional `-h`/`--help`:

```
$ scrapy crawl --help
Usage
=====
  scrapy crawl [options] <spider>

Run a spider

Options
=======
--help, -h              show this help message and exit
-a NAME=VALUE           set spider argument (may be repeated)
--output=FILE, -o FILE  dump scraped items into FILE (use - for stdout)
--output-format=FORMAT, -t FORMAT
                        format to use for dumping items with -o

Global Options
--------------
--logfile=FILE          log file. if omitted stderr will be used
--loglevel=LEVEL, -L LEVEL
                        log level (default: DEBUG)
--nolog                 disable logging completely
--profile=FILE          write python cProfile stats to FILE
--pidfile=FILE          write process ID to FILE
--set=NAME=VALUE, -s NAME=VALUE
                        set/override setting (may be repeated)
--pdb                   enable pdb on failure
```

See the entry for `-o`:

```
--output=FILE, -o FILE  dump scraped items into FILE (use - for stdout)
```

See the entry for `-t`:

```
--output-format=FORMAT, -t FORMAT
                        format to use for dumping items with -o
```

Putting it together

```
$ scrapy crawl redditSearch -o reddit.csv -t csv
```

means "*dump the results of the crawl command into a reddit.csv file and use CSV format when writing the file*".

You can also check the [Using the scrapy tool](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#using-the-scrapy-tool) section of the official docs. The command usage and options may differ per command.